# Why do threads not work properly?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm solving a university exercise. The father process gives via pipe a number (*nThreads*) read in a file to the son process. The son has to execute *nThreads* threads and sleep for *nThreads* secs, and each thread has to print a random number given by the son process and sleep for that random number of secs.
The processes print all OK, but the threads don't. What didn't work in my code?

```
...
#include <pthread.h>

void exitError() {
 write(2, "Error!\n", 7);
 exit(1);
}

void *doThread(void* args) {
 long rnd = (long)args;
 printf("Random number = %ld", rnd);
 sleep(rnd);
 pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 int pid, n, piped[2];

 pipe(piped);

 if ((pid=fork()) == -1) {
    write(1, "Error!\n", 4);
    exit(1);
 }
 else if (pid == 0) {   //son
    int nThreads;
    close(piped[1]);
    read(piped[0], &nThreads, 2);
    printf("\nI have to create %d threads\n\n", nThreads);
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = (pthread_t *) malloc(nThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    int random;
    random = rand();
    pthread_create(&threads[nThreads], NULL, doThread, random);

    sleep(nThreads);
    exit(0);
 }
 else {                 //father
    signal(SIGALRM, exitError);
    alarm(10);
    if (argc != 2) {
        write(1, "Command error!\n", 24);
    }   
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    char buf[1];
    n = read(fd, buf, 1);
    int nThreads = atoi(buf);
    printf("I say %d to my son\n", nThreads);
    close(piped[0]);
    write(piped[1], &nThreads, 2);
    wait(NULL);
    alarm(0);
    exit(0);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Forgive me if I did something wrong, it is the first time I ask something here.

Comment: You need to `pthread_join()` with your threads.

Comment: `int* random; *random = ...` is wrong. Lethal wrong.

Comment: Sorry you are right. I fixed it, but threads still seem not to work.

Comment: Unless you're on an old 16-bit system, `sizeof(int)` (or `sizeof(nThreads)`) is *not* equal to `2`.

Comment: @Pottercomuneo: Your "fix" for the `int *`-issue is, of course, incorrect. You seem undecided whether it is an `int`, a `long`, or a `long*`. These things are not interchangeable. Also, you *still*  don't `pthread_join()` with your threads, so you're racing the process termination, and it'll probably win for high values of `random()` (or `&random`, as the case is currently).

Comment: Does your compiler not tell you anything about converting from `int` to `void *` without a cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes:

First, you're passing pointer to `int random` but in the thread you convert the argument (pointer) to the number. Either you have to cast the `int random` to a pointer or in the thread cast `args` to `long *` and read the memory from that pointer. The latter will actually stop working once you launch several threads as you'll change the variable content in the meantime or even leave the scope of that variable.

Secondly, you don't wait for the thread(s). Use `pthread_join` to wait for thread.

Third, you run only single thread, you need to create in loop from `0` to `nThreads` and once launching all of them, call `pthread_join` in similar loop.

Fourth, the size of `int` is 4 on most platforms while you send only 2 bytes. This may work on low endian platforms but will fail on big endian. Use `sizeof(int)` for both `write` and `read` to make it more portable.

Comment: There's also the issue of calling `atoi()` on a single `char` (obviously unterminated)...

Comment: Thank you, I understood all my mistakes. There's one thing that makes me think about it, the exercise says "The main thread does not have to wait for the other threads to end". This is why I thought that I didn't have to use `pthread_join`. Is it wrong?

Comment: Well, if it's said, you probably don't have to. However I'm not sure about portability when you exit main thread and not the others. It may work differently on different systems, one some it may exit the whole process, on others it may wait for other threads. Secondly in this case you definitely have to make sure that you don't pass pointer to `random` as it will come out of scope and will be no longer available from the threads.